# Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 80))

Tags: ruby, http, httparty

I'm trying to use the library `HTTParty`, but whenever I run the code below I receive an error.

Code:

```
require 'httparty'
response = HTTParty.get('http://example.com')
```

When I run the code I receive the error: `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 80))`.
I don't get any error when I run the same code in `net/http`. I don't know if this helps, but the system I'm running is Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit .

Comment: are you running this from a local server? in the context of an application?  can you post the full backtrace errors?  Also did you try with `response = HTTParty.get('https://example.com')` ?

Comment: I'm not running this on a local server, but just my laptop computer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I know that this is late, but using `https://example.com` instead of `http://example.com` was the solution to my problem.

Comment: it is never late for future us, It helped me a lot

Comment: Helped me - I was being an idiot and had forgotten the protocol entirely :D